# Python Dataframe - apply function on selected rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which has two columns `A` and `B`. Some rows have NaN for `A`. I want to apply a function to rows with `NaN` in `A` based on the value in column `B`.

I tried something like:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'A']=df['B'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

I know it won't work but can't figure out the right way.

Comment: How do you know it won't work? Did you get an error message? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: It does not work because the length of two sides of the equation don't match

Comment: You would be surprised if you actually tried. Because it actually _works_. And it works because the assignment expression is not an equation.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'A'] = df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'B'].map(func)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#This should work. 
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x.B) if np.isnan(x.A) else x.A, axis=1)
```

**Setup**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0},
 'B': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 20, 4: 20, 5: 300, 6: 300, 7: 20}})

Out[765]: 
     A    B
0  1.0    1
1  1.0    1
2  NaN    1
3  NaN   20
4  NaN   20
5  1.0  300
6  1.0  300
7  1.0   20

def func(x):
    return x*x
```

**Solution**

```
#check d.A for nan inside the lambda can call the function only when d.A is nan.
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x.B) if np.isnan(x.A) else x.A, axis=1)

df
Out[769]: 
       A    B
0    1.0    1
1    1.0    1
2    1.0    1
3  400.0   20
4  400.0   20
5    1.0  300
6    1.0  300
7    1.0   20
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get error:  'isnan' not supported for the input types. Is that because my A column is string type?

Comment: What's the type of your column A? What's in it? You can check the column type by 'df.info()'